# Access not allowing users to delete rows

Tags: ms-access

I've got a problem with being able to delete rows of data in a form (for example, if I need to delete a row that I just duplicated, I can't do it).  Here's a little bit about my database.  I have three different habitats (forest, wetland, grassland) and each habitat has its own data entry form for entering a list of the species encountered at each site.  The only difference in the forms is the name, all code is the same as are the settings for the forms and the controls.  The forms consist of a main form (ForestSpeciesMain) and a subform (ForestSpeciesSubform).

My problem is that I can't delete rows of data in the forest form.  I click on the far left box just outside the row to select it and then hit right click to delete, and the selection for "Delete Record" is grayed out.  I can't delete simply by hitting delete, either.

I've run the "Documenter" to double check the settings for the main form and the sub form and in both instances "AllowDeletions" is true, so technically I could delete records, but I can't.  Does anyone have any ideas for what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Can you delete a row from the query or table that the subform is based on? In other words, is it to do with the form, the query or the table? If it is the query or table, it may be to do with relationships.

Comment: What's the recordsource of the subform you can't delete from? If it's a saved query, what's the SQL of the saved query?

Answer (score 0):

The recordsource for the subform is a table, dbo_ForestSpeciesListM (SQL Server tables, Access used for data entry) and I can't delete records directly from the table, either.

Comment: Sounds like a server-side issue. Try deleting the linked table and recreating it. It could be that changes to that table's structure (changes to fields/indexes/etc.) have made the linked table uneditable. This is very, very common, and as a matter of course, I delete and recreate any linked table when I change the server-side table/view it is pointing to.